# PHP CLI corrupts executed file

Tags: php, windows, websocket, filesystems

#### Problem description

Sometimes after running **PHP CLI**, the primary executed PHP file is erased. It's simply gone.
The file is missing / corrupted. Undelete (Netbeans History - revert delete) still shows the file, but it is not possible to recover it. It is also not possible to replace / reinstate the file with the identical filename.

[image: Netbeans history - revert delete]

#### Trial and error attempts

The issue occurs on (3) different computers, all Windows 10 or Windows 11.
I've used different versions of PHP (php-7.3.10-Win32-VC15-x64, php-8.1.4-Win32-vs16-x64).

The code is not doing any file IO at all. It uses a React event loop, listening to a websocket - "server_worklistobserver.php":

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$context = array(
    'tls' => array(
        'local_cert' => "certificate.crt",
        'local_pk' => "certificate.key",
        'allow_self_signed' => true, // Set to false in production
        'verify_peer' => false
    )
);

// Set up websocket server
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$application = new Ratchet\App('my.domain.com', 8443, 'tls://0.0.0.0', $loop, $context);

// Set up controller component
$controller = new WorklistObserver();
$application->route('/checkworklist', $controller, array('*'));

$application->run();
die('-server stopped-');
```

The disappearance happens when the PHP execution is cancelled. Either by Ctrl-Break, or when run as a service, a service stop/restart.

Execution is started by: `php.exe server_worklistobserver.php` in a dos-box (cmd).

Using administrator permissions has no effect. Performing a harddisk scan has no effect; there are no issues found. The issue is rather persistent, but not regular; it seems to happen by chance.
Associated PHP files are left intact.
The issue has never occurred on the Apache driven PHP execution.

#### Please help

What could I do different? Does have anyone have a similar experience? I can't find anything alike on the internet...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My one and only guess is that a malware engine is quarantining it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, Chris! Indeed, I found the entries in the quarantaine of my virusscanner. I've added an exception rule and don't expect to have this happen again.